# TypeError: plotImages() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_images' Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The error i got: TypeError: plotImages() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_images'

Please do let me know if you have an idea. This is the code:

```
categoriesList=["airplane","automobile","bird", "cat", "deer", "dog", "frog", "horse", "ship", "truck"]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
def plotImages(x_test, images_arr, labels_arr, nx_images=8):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_images, n_images, figsize=(9,9))
    axes = axes.flatten()
    
    for i in range(100):
        rand = random.randint(0, x_test.shape[0] -1)
        img = images_arr[rand]
        ax = axes[i]
    
        ax.imshow( img, cmap="Greys_r")
        ax.set_xticks(())
        ax.set_yticks(())
        
        predict_x=model2000.predict([[x_test[rand]]])
        label=categoriesList[predictions[0]]  
        
        if labels_arr[rand][predictions[0]] == 0:
            ax.set_title(label, fontsize=18 - n_images, color="red")
        else:
            ax.set_title(label, fontsize=18 - n_images) 
        
    plot = plt.tight_layout()
    return plot
  
display (plotImages(x_test, data_test_picture, y_test, n_images=10))
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images, only as text. Only then you will get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the argument as `nx_images` in function definition, but doesn't seem to use it anywhere in the code. Try changing it.

Comment: After doing that i get an error as 
NameError: name 'x_test' is not defined

Comment: Did you define the x_test? What data do you have in x_test.

Comment: Now i'm getting a value error 
--->  display (plotImages(x_test, data_test_picture, y_test, n_images=10))
 
--->          predict_x=model2000.predict([[x_test[rand]]])

Comment: @Eng - you keep moving the goal post, if this answer helped solved the one you asked about you should consider accepting it. any others you should try to fix yourself and then raise a question if you still need help.